# Uploader for photo working for iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, photo, file-upload

I have try : http://valums.com/ajax-upload/, and http://www.plupload.com/, and http://www.uploadify.com/ but NONE is able to upload a photo to my webpage when i do it with the iphone... why, and How do you do that ?, is there and API that do that ?

Comment: These are all Flash based, and there is no Flash on iOS. I guess that is the problem. I don't know what the iOS people do in this case - consider adding some iOS related tags so they see this question

Comment: Check out PhoneGap. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Aurigma Up](http://www.aurigma.com/iphone/)